# Rails - showing user page after signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show the a users page after they sign up but getting `Couldn't find User without an ID`.

On the error page I tested `params` in the console and it returned `=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show"} permitted: false>`

Form:

```
<%= form_with url: users_path,  :class => "user_sign_in_form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field "user[email]", placeholder: "email", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.text_field "user[username]", placeholder: "username", :class => "form_box"%>
  <%= form.text_field "user[password]", placeholder: "password", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

Create action:

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  
    if @user.save
      redirect_to model: @users
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Show action:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: redirect_to user_path(@user)

Answer (score 0):

@razvans commented with the answer :)

```
redirect_to user_path(@user)
```